# How to install plesk using YUM on centOS 5?

Tags: vps

i have a vps running centOS 5.4 LAMP and i want to install Plesk panel, so i've installed .ART packages using SSH like they said here : http://www.atomicorp.com/channels/plesk/ , i tried to execute : `yum install plesk` but i got :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirrors.netdna.com
 * atomic: www5.atomicorp.com
 * base: yum.singlehop.com
 * extras: mirror.steadfast.net
 * updates: www.gtlib.gatech.edu
atomic                                                   | 1.9 kB     00:00
atomic/primary_db                                        | 425 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
No package plesk available.
Nothing to do
```

Means that no package called "plesk" found. the question is what's the command to install Plesk in my vps or is there another "easy" way to do it, because i'm not really pro in sys administration :)

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure YUM to retrieve the package from the Atomiccorp repository i.e.

```
[plesk]
name=Plesk Server Administrator
baseurl=http://www.atomicorp.com/channels/plesk/latest/fedora/$releasever/$basearch
gpgcheck=0
```